# Mapbox how to dissolve cluster on click of it

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, mapbox, markerclusterer

I am using Mapbox sdk in my project. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/

I have got the basic clustering working but my question is how to i dissolve a cluster further on click of it.

eg. I have a cluster with 8 markers. On click it should further zoom in, not just one level but to a point where all 8 markers are on screen with maximum zoom possible.(some markers out of these 8 can be clustered)

I tried 
[mapView zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(south, west)
                                                northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(north, east) animated:YES]; 
but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how ended up doing it:

```
- (void)tapOnAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation onMap:(RMMapView *)map {

    if (annotation.isClusterAnnotation) {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D southwestCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D northeastCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;

        for (RMAnnotation *plot in annotation.clusteredAnnotations) {

            CGFloat latititude = plot.coordinate.latitude;
            CGFloat longitude = plot.coordinate.longitude;

            if (southwestCoordinate.latitude > fabsf(latititude)) southwestCoordinate.latitude = latititude;
            if (southwestCoordinate.longitude > fabsf(longitude)) southwestCoordinate.longitude = longitude;

            if (northeastCoordinate.latitude < fabsf(latititude)) northeastCoordinate.latitude = latititude;
            if (northeastCoordinate.longitude < fabsf(longitude)) northeastCoordinate.longitude = longitude;

        }

        [self.mapView zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest:southwestCoordinate northEast:northeastCoordinate animated:YES];

   }
}
```

Basically, what's happening here is that I'm storing the outermost region's bounding coordinates `southwestCoordinate` and `northeastCoordinate` to the tapped annotation (in this case, the cluster). Then, for each annotation within the cluster, we're checking to see if it's absolute distance from that "center" coordinate is the greatest in the group.

Seems to work pretty well for me.

Comment: I started with a similar approach but I believe my answer is an improvement on this one.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will do a better job of zooming in on your cluster points, expanding to a level where some or all points are unclustered:

```
    // 1. Start with a maximum (world-wide) bounding box
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topRight = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(180, -90);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-180, 90);

    // 2. Derive the minimum bounding box coordinates that contains all cluster points, by "squeezing in" on their coordinates
    for (RMAnnotation *a in annotation.clusteredAnnotations) {

        if (a.coordinate.latitude < topRight.latitude) {
            topRight.latitude = a.coordinate.latitude;
        }
        if (a.coordinate.longitude > topRight.longitude) {
            topRight.longitude = a.coordinate.longitude;
        }

        if (a.coordinate.latitude > bottomLeft.latitude) {
            bottomLeft.latitude = a.coordinate.latitude;
        }
        if (a.coordinate.longitude < bottomLeft.longitude) {
            bottomLeft.longitude = a.coordinate.longitude;
        }
    }

    CLLocation *sw = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:topRight.latitude longitude:topRight.longitude];
    CLLocation *ne = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:bottomLeft.latitude longitude:bottomLeft.longitude];

    // 3. Calculate the distance in meters across the calculated bounding box
    CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [ne distanceFromLocation:sw];
    // 4. Adjust the map view's meters per pixel setting so that the bounding box fits nicely within the map views bounds (which is equivalent to zooming)
    [self.mapView setMetersPerPixel:(distanceInMeters / (self.mapView.frame.size.width * 0.7)) animated:YES];
    // 5. Center on the midpoint of the bounding box
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:[self midPointBetween:topRight and:bottomLeft] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

GoogleMaps

Used: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils for clustering

"Uncluster cluster" :D

**Swift 3**

```
if let cluster = marker.userData as? GMUCluster {
let boxConstant = 0.01
    var southwestCoordinate = cluster.position
    var northeastCoordinate = cluster.position

    for clusterItem in cluster.items {

      let latitude = clusterItem.position.latitude
      let longitude = clusterItem.position.longitude

      if southwestCoordinate.latitude > latitude {
        southwestCoordinate.latitude = latitude
      }
      if southwestCoordinate.longitude > longitude {
        southwestCoordinate.longitude = longitude
      }
      if northeastCoordinate.latitude < latitude {
        northeastCoordinate.latitude = latitude
      }
      if northeastCoordinate.longitude < longitude {
        northeastCoordinate.longitude = longitude
      }

    }

    // Create Box
    southwestCoordinate.longitude += boxConstant
    southwestCoordinate.latitude -= boxConstant
    northeastCoordinate.longitude -= boxConstant
    northeastCoordinate.latitude += boxConstant
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southwestCoordinate, coordinate: northeastCoordinate)
    self.mapView.moveCamera(GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would add this as a comment of the metatheoric answer but i have not enough rep.

I think that with that fasbf it makes a bad calculation for negative coordinates and it works better without it. Am i right?

```
- (void)tapOnAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation onMap:(RMMapView *)map {
    if (annotation.isClusterAnnotation) {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D southwestCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D northeastCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;

        for (RMAnnotation *plot in annotation.clusteredAnnotations) {

            CGFloat latitude = plot.coordinate.latitude;
            CGFloat longitude = plot.coordinate.longitude;

            if (southwestCoordinate.latitude > latitude) southwestCoordinate.latitude = latitude;
            if (southwestCoordinate.longitude > longitude) southwestCoordinate.longitude = longitude;

            if (northeastCoordinate.latitude < latitude) northeastCoordinate.latitude = latitude;
            if (northeastCoordinate.longitude < longitude) northeastCoordinate.longitude = longitude;

        }

        [map zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest:southwestCoordinate northEast:northeastCoordinate animated:YES];    
    }
}
```